# Replicate TCP connection

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, client-server

I have a desktop app that connects to a server by using TPC and gets some data from it (it is in a local environment and it doesn't need any type of authentication). I have to develop an app that connects to this server and gets the same data but the only thing that I have are the packets captured by wireshark where I can se the data and establishion of the connection.

My question is if there is any way to replicate this TCP connection between my client and the server sending the same packets I captured with wireshark.

Comment: Yes;  You write a server that replies to the client with the expected packets.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, e.g. use `socat` to capture the stream in one (or both) directions, then replay with `socat` again (if that's what you want to do). You can also export the stream from Wireshark, etc., etc.

Comment: @dirkt thank you or answering but the idea is tht only my client connection is going to be alive so I caon't stream the packets of the desktopp app client because it is going to be closed

Comment: Sorry, but after your comment I'm not quite sure what you are talking about. I thought you wanted to capture the datastream between an existing server S and an existing client C1, so you can write a client C2 for the same server and test it with the existing data stream. If you want to do anything else, please explain.